# Hooking any AI chatbot to Facebook chat

Tags: facebook, artificial-intelligence, chat

I haven't tried anything on this, but is it possible? If it is, is there a way of making a plugin for firefox or chrome? or making a software that enables you to hook ai chatbot to Facebook chat. I really want to use cleverbot or iGod.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to the facebook chat via the [XMPP API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/), though I believe using it to connect a bot or anything that is not user-to-user chat is a violation of the rules.

Comment: It is only for personal use and research.

Answer (score 0):

There are many services such as Kommunicate and ManyChat, that provides a way to automate facebook conversations using AI Chatbot.

Signup at [Kommunicate](https://www.kommunicate.io), visit Integrations section. Select Facebook, then select the Facebook page and connect. After that, go to Bot Integration section and connect it with the bot.

Here is a detailed instructions on th same: https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/facebook-chatbot/